# Monday's Capturing Donimoes Problem

Tags: sliding-blocks, dominoes

I just published my [Donimoes](https://donkirkby.github.io/donimoes/) collection of new games and puzzles as a book, so
I'm celebrating by posting some bonus problems this week.

Capturing Donimoes is a puzzle I designed to feel like a safari in heavy traffic.

#### Goal

The goal is to collect all the dominoes by sliding matching numbers next to
each other.

#### Moves

There are only two ways a domino can move: matching and adding.

##### Matching

Move a domino one space along its long axis so that it ends up with at least
one of its numbers matching an adjacent number on a neighbouring domino. Then
collect the domino you moved and any dominoes that match it, by removing them
from the pattern. In this example, the threes match, so you collect both
dominoes: solution found!

[image: Example capturing move]

##### Adding

Move a domino one space along its long axis so that it ends up with at least
one of its numbers next to an adjacent number that adds up to six. With an
adding move, no dominoes are removed. In this example, the two adds up with the
four above it to make six.

[image: Example adding move]

Sometimes, you can collect more than two dominoes at once. In the first
example, the two matches twos on both of the other dominoes, and you collect
all three dominoes. In the second example, the two matches the two to the left,
and the four matches the four above it. You collect all three dominoes.

[image: Triple capture examples]

##### Stay Connected

All the dominoes must stay in one connected group, you can't split the group
after moving or after removing the matching dominoes.

#### Today's Problem

Here's a problem to solve for today. Try to solve it in the fewest possible
moves, and post your solution.

[image: Today's problem]

If you like this puzzle, watch for more challenging problems later in the week.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was a cool puzzle. I have never seen it before. After playing around with many different wrong paths, I finally found a correct one using 14 moves.

> [image]

Move count: 1

> [image]

Move count: 4

> [image]

Move count: 7

> [image]

Move count: 9

> [image]

Move count: 10

> [image]

Move count: 11

> [image]

Move count: 13

> [image]

Move count: 14