# Wednesday's Capturing Donimoes Problem

Tags: sliding-blocks, dominoes

I just published my [Donimoes](https://donkirkby.github.io/donimoes/) collection of new games and puzzles as a book, so
I'm celebrating by posting a few bonus problems this week. The puzzle is
Capturing Donimoes, which I designed to feel like a safari in heavy traffic. See
[Monday's problem](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/115981/38) for the complete rules, and remember the two types of move:
matching and adding.

Today's problem is a little bigger and a little more challenging. Good luck, and
post your solution as an answer.

[image: Starting position]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another super cool little puzzle! Have you considered making this into an app? I'd buy it.

This one was definitely more complex than Monday's Donimoes puzzle, but even more fun and satisfying.

> [image]

> [image]

> [image]

> [image]

> [image]

> [image]

> [image]

> [image]

> [image]

> [image]

> [image]

> [image]

> [image]

Comment: I'm glad you're enjoying the puzzle. I'll post one more bonus problem this week, and you can find the original 20 problems in my new book or on [my web site](https://donkirkby.github.io/donimoes/). I've thought about making an app or browser version, but I really like sliding the physical dominoes around. It's also computationally expensive to find good problems.