# Friday's Capturing Donimoes Problem

Tags: sliding-blocks, dominoes

I just published my [Donimoes](https://donkirkby.github.io/donimoes/) collection of new games and puzzles as a book, so
I'm celebrating by posting a few bonus problems this week. The puzzle is
Capturing Donimoes, which I designed to feel like a safari in heavy traffic. See
[Monday's problem](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/115981/38) for complete rules and an example solution.

Today's problem is even bigger and more challenging than [Wednesday's](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/116015/38), it uses
the complete set of double-six dominoes. Good luck, and post your solution as an
answer.

[image: Starting position]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another fun Donimoes problem. Thanks for posting these here.

> [image]

> [image]

> [image]

> [image]

> [image]

> [image]

> [image]

> [image]

> [image]

> [image]

> [image]

> [image]

> [image]

> [image]